# Problem merging duplicate row into first row with mysql

Tags: mysql, concatenation

can you give me an example request showing how I can combine two duplicate lines merge one?

| id | name | no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aaa | 1,2,3 |
| 124 | aaa | 4,5,6 |
| 125 | aaa | 7,8,9 |

i want this

| id | name | no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aaa | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 |

I researched whether I could update with concat, but I couldn't get any results.

Comment: You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) but you may want to rethink serializing those values in to a single value, unless you will only ever want them verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do the update:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(id) AS id, GROUP_CONCAT(no) AS no
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY name
) agg ON mytable.id = agg.id
SET mytable.no = agg.no;
```

And then do the delete:

```sql
DELETE m1
FROM mytable m1
JOIN mytable m2 ON m1.name = m2.name AND m1.id > m2.id;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lOWFwfas).

Comment: error #1260 - Row 393 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: You can increase [group_concat_max_length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY` inside the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) :

```
select min(id) as id, name, group_concat(no ORDER BY id ASC) as no
from mytable
group by name
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/VR8v_IYl)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have listed the data, but what I need is to update this data. @SelVazi